# How do I manipulate model data in the background for a data visualization in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I'm currently using Rails with D3.js to create a data visualization using model data. What I've done in the view is to extract the model data, aggregate it into categories, and set it as an array of hashes that D3.js can read.

However, I think this slows down page load and I'd like to bring this logic into the background somehow while maintaining instant syncing between model data and the graph (which means when someone updates the model data, the visualization automatically updates itself). Is there a way to do it that gels with the Rails framework?

Ultimately, my goal is really to speed up page load for scale as in the future the dataset will get larger. So any alternative suggestions are welcome.

This is the code pertaining to the data manipulation:

```
<% @startup_fundings.each do |startup_funding| %>
  <% if startup_funding.startup %>
    // check if startup belongs to Southeast Asia
    <% if countries.any? { |country| startup_funding.startup.locations.include?(country) } == true && startup_funding.amount != nil %>

      // split string by individual keywords
      <% funding_round_split = [] %>
      <% funding_round_split = startup_funding.startup.product_markets.split(", ") if startup_funding.startup.product_markets %>


      // check if vertical exists in funding round
      <% funding_round_split.each do |funding_round| %>
        <% [ ['Hr', 'HR'], ['Bi', 'BI'], ["Crm", "CRM"], ["Lbs", "LBS"], ["Saas", "SaaS"]].each do |replacement| 
          funding_round.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1]) 
        end %>
        var fundingRound = "<%= funding_round %>";
        var exists = false;
        for (i = 0; i < graphData.length; i++) {
            if (graphData[i].vertical == fundingRound) {
                exists = true;
                var order = i;
            }
        }
        // if vertical does not exist, add new vertical
        if (exists == false) {
            graphData.push({'vertical': fundingRound, 
                            'amount': <%= startup_funding.amount %>, 
                            'deals': [{'company': '<%= startup_funding.startup.company_name %>', 
                                       'url': '<%= startup_funding.startup.company_name.downcase.delete(' ').gsub('.', '-') %>', 
                                       'amount': <%= startup_funding.amount %>}]
                          });

        } else {
            // if vertical exists, add up funding amount
            graphData[order].amount = graphData[order].amount + <%= startup_funding.amount %>;
            var duplicateRound = false;
            // cycle through all funding rounds in a vertical
            for (j = 0; j < graphData[order].deals.length; j++) {
              // if company in funding round matches iterative company name, indicate it exists
              if (graphData[order].deals[j].company == '<%= startup_funding.startup.company_name %>') {
                duplicateRound = true;
                var order1 = j;
              }
            }
            if (duplicateRound == false) {
              graphData[order].deals.push({
                'company': '<%= startup_funding.startup.company_name %>', 
                'url': '<%= startup_funding.startup.company_name.downcase.delete(' ').gsub('.', '-') %>',
                'amount': <%= startup_funding.amount %>
              });
            } else {
                graphData[order].deals[order1].amount = graphData[order].deals[order1].amount + <%= startup_funding.amount %>;
              }
          }
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```